# AdaptiveChoiceSetInput is not working as expected when selected by default

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have created a Bot in MSTeams and I am using Adaptive controls. In one of the cards, I am displaying checkboxes that are by default selected. If I uncheck one of the checkboxes from the list and click on the Submit button, It considers all the checkboxes to be unchecked.
Below is the C# code I used to create an adaptive card.

```
                var card = new AdaptiveCard("1.5");
                AdaptiveChoice choice = new AdaptiveChoice();

                var chkBox = new AdaptiveChoiceSetInput();
                card.Body.Add(chkBox);
                chkBox.Spacing = AdaptiveSpacing.Medium;
                chkBox.IsMultiSelect = true;
                chkBox.Style = AdaptiveChoiceInputStyle.Expanded;
                chkBox.Id = "test";
                chkBox.Wrap = true;
                chkBox.Value = "1,2";
                chkBox.IsRequired = true;
                chkBox.ErrorMessage = "please select at least one option.";

                choice = new AdaptiveChoice();
                choice.Title = "Red";
                choice.Value = "1";
                chkBox.Choices.Add(choice);

                choice = new AdaptiveChoice();
                choice.Title = "Orange";
                choice.Value = "2";
                chkBox.Choices.Add(choice);

                AdaptiveAction action = new AdaptiveSubmitAction();
                action.Type = "Action.Submit";
                action.Title = texts["btnConfirm"];
                action.AdditionalProperties.Add("data", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "id", "Testingsss" } });
                card.Actions.Add(action);

                var act = MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment()
                {
                    Content = card,
                    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType
                });

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(act);
```

Here is the screenshot of an issue.

[image: multiselect checkbox issue.]

Comment: We checked this at our end, and we observed that if you unselect 2nd check box it works fine-https://i.stack.imgur.com/svoUY.png. If you unselect 1st checkbox it gives error-https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sezfh.png. We will check this behavior internally and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, Meghana for your comment. But In my case, I am experiencing the same behavior when I uncheck the second checkbox. Anyway, I hope the fix will handle all the scenarios.

Comment: We raised a bug for this, we will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT is there any update on this bug?

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have any update to share. We are following up with the engineering team for updates. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Meghana-MSFT, Please let me know when I can expect this bug to be resolved.

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience caused to you. We do not have any update to share. We are following up with the engineering team for updates. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, can you follow up for this ticket and let me know when can we expect this to get resolved.

Comment: We are following up for updates. We will keep you posted. Thank you.